# Why do I get ACCESS_REFUSED using op-rabbit but not NewMotion/Akka?

Tags: scala, rabbitmq, akka

Using these parameters:

```
canada {
  hosts = ["dd.weather.gc.ca"]
  username = "anonymous"
  password = "anonymous"
  port = 5671
  exchange = "xpublic"
  queue = "q_anonymous_gsk"
  routingKey = "v02.post.observations.swob-ml.#"
  requestedHeartbeat = 300
  ssl = true
}
```

I can connect to a weather service in Canada using [NewMotion/Akka](https://github.com/NewMotion/akka-rabbitmq), but when I try [op-rabbit](https://github.com/SpinGo/op-rabbit), I get:

```
ACCESS_REFUSED - access to exchange 'xpublic' in vhost '/' refused for user 'anonymous'
```

```
[INFO] [foo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] [akka://foo/user/$a/connection] akka://foo/user/$a/connection connected to amqp://anonymous@{dd.weather.gc.ca:5671}:5671//
[INFO] [foo-op-rabbit.default-channel-dispatcher-6] [akka://foo/user/$a/connection/$a] akka://foo/user/$a/connection/$a connected
[INFO] [foo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://foo/user/$a/connection/confirmed-publisher-channel] akka://foo/user/$a/connection/confirmed-publisher-channel connected
[INFO] [foo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://foo/user/$a/connection/$b] akka://foo/user/$a/connection/$b connected
[ERROR] [foo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://foo/user/$a/subscription-q_anonymous_gsk-1] Connection related error while trying to re-bind a consumer to q_anonymous_gsk. Waiting in anticipating of a new channel.
...
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=403, reply-text=ACCESS_REFUSED - access to exchange 'xpublic' in vhost '/' refused for user 'anonymous', class-id=40, method-id=10)
```

The following works in NewMotion/Akka:

```
val inQueue = "q_anonymous_gsk"
val inExchange = "xpublic"
val canadaQueue = canadaChannel.queueDeclare(inQueue, false, true, false, null).getQueue
canadaChannel.queueBind(canadaQueue, inExchange, inQueue)

val consumer = new DefaultConsumer(canadaChannel) {
  override def handleDelivery(consumerTag: String, envelope: Envelope, properties: BasicProperties, body: Array[Byte]) {
    val s = fromBytes(body)
    if (republishElsewhere) {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
canadaChannel.basicConsume(canadaQueue, true, consumer)
```

but using `op-rabbit` like this:

```
val inQueue = "q_anonymous_gsk"
val inExchange = "xpublic"
val inRoutingKey = "v02.post.observations.swob-ml.#""

val rabbitCanada: ActorRef = actorSystem.actorOf(Props(classOf[RabbitControl], connParamsCanada))

def runSubscription(): SubscriptionRef = Subscription.run(rabbitCanada) {
  channel(qos = 3) {
    consume(topic(queue(inQueue), List(inRoutingKey))) {
      (body(as[String]) & routingKey) { (msg, key) =>
        ack
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get the `ACCESS_REFUSED` error near the top of this post. Why? How do I fix this if I want to use `op-rabbit`?

Answer (score 0):

[image: RabbitMQ console]

Have you tried to use the correct vhost with permission to anonymous user